# Import data from external sheets named after dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have 2 sheets one changes by the end of the day everyday and inserts its data into the other master spreadsheet and names the sheet after the days date.

The week starts on monday and finishes sunday, I want to access cells for each day of the week in each of the spreadsheets pertaining to that week but I am having problems with my formula. here is what i have already:

```
 =importrange("1sll-WvYyfAi1Hux7WW3NnHKLorSFJ_tzUFUO7bZbFTQ", "TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+2!B8:B8")
```

It is not finding the sheet that is named 28-04-2014

Answer (score 0):

`"TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+2!B8:B8"` is not returning what you expect. Replace it by

```
TEXT(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+2,"dd-mm-yyyy") & "!B8:B8"
```

Related

- [How to convert a date to a string in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40857180/1595451)