# How to convert a date to a string in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to convert a date into a string in a google sheet.

I have one date field that has varying formats. I want create another column that's literally just the same but as a text. For example, if I had the following data

```
date       date_as_string
12-05-2016 '12-05-2016
12/5/2016  '12/5/2016
2016-12-10 '2016-12-10
```

Where the ' is just to denote that it is a string note a date.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the `TEXTJOIN` function. Give an empty delimiter, `TRUE` for the ignore empty, the referenced cell as text1, and don't supply anything for text2.

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1)
```

Done.

Comment: A nasty trick, but far the best answer!  (I've Tried all others, but none really worked well)

Comment: @Richard I think learning Perl taught me to look for the 'nasty' tricks which make life easier in the end.

Comment: In my case this was actually the best solution, because in `CONCAT()` with date cell was rendering it as a number and I needed it as a text, so this worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 76):

You can use [the `TEXT` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139).

```
=Text(cellReference, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I realize I phrased my question very poorly. What I meant was I have a date field. It might have the format mm-dd-yyyy or it might have a format mm/dd/yyyy. I would like to create a new column that is literally just the same but as text with the same format. I'll update my original question as appropriate.

Comment: That's ... a completely different question from what you asked lol. Like not even close.

Comment: Right. Sorry. I remember trying to use the TEXT formula, but it seems like you can't just specify using the same format.

Comment: TEXT is still the way to do this, but you need a way of determining the format on a string per string basis.

Answer (score 17):

`=TEXT(now(),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

[image]

This cell is now a string.

Answer (score 10):

1. copy the column to another column
2. select the copied column
3. go to menu 'Format' --> 'Number' --> 'Plain text'

Comment: I used this with my Google spreadsheet. The dates look 1 on on the sheet but but reading them comes up with something different. Just select the rows you want to fix and the do # 3 above.

Answer (score 5):

to concatenate text to date you can do this:

```
=CONCATENATE("today is: ", TEXT(HOY(), "dd-mm-yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 4):

there's no way to detect the format of dates in google sheets. But you may use [`getDisplayValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) property. Paste this code into script editor:

```
function repeatAsText(A1Notation, sheet) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (sheet) { sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet); }
  else { sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); }
  var range = sheet.getRange(A1Notation);
 
  return range.getDisplayValues();
}
```

and then use it as ususl formula:

`=repeatAsText("A1:A3")`

[image]

A1Notation -- string like "A1" or "B3:AD15".

sheet -- name of sheet, like "Sheet1". It is optional, use ActiveSheet if omitted