# GoogleSheet Formula to Combine and Expand two columns of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns of data (based on other sheets, but basically a list of clients and available dates)

[image]

Is it possible to create a list of the clients and months in an expanded list (for me to create a data table with other values)

Been trying, but can't even get close, I could do it using a script, but was hoping to create a "live" sheet.

here's a sample sheet with the data in screenshot in it
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IYL3uErowtrRfRAhBH8GDcSqsSBvW3HaHqvIE50FG1U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: **Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.**

Comment: Apologies, I'd be happy to do that, but not actually sure what that means. If I copy and paste the text from my table is just comes up as loads of text joined together

Comment: Markdown [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) require a particular syntax.  Personally, I use the free online service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDEX(FLATTEN(A1:A4&" - "&TRANSPOSE(map(C1:C12,lambda(mths,text(mths,"MMM YYYY"))))))`

h/t

- player0: [Generate all possible combinations for Columns(cross join or Cartesian product)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775825/1330560)
- Alexander: [How to convert a date to a string in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857226/1330560)

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

Comment: wow thanks for that, and some functions i've never used before so going to have a read on how it works